# Copy-constructor calls for custom sorting predicate in boost::multi_index_container

Tags: c++, boost, copy-constructor, boost-multi-index

I am using `boost::multi_index_container` to provide multiple views and sorting orders for a set of objects. Recently, I wanted to sort the container using a custom sorting predicate that (in essence) pre-calculates attribute values for all objects and then uses these values to sort them (see below for example code).

The container gets sorted correctly, but I noted that sorting with this predicate takes much longer that sorting with a predicate whose `operator()` simply accesses an *internal* property of my objects.

Further investigation showed that the (implicitly defined) copy-constructor of my predicate was called very often. Since each copy of the predicate contains a copy of the complete attribute map, this took a long time.

I have since solved this by adding an internal attribute to my objects, but I am still not convinced that this is the best of course of action. So, I would like to know:

- Why is the copy constructor called this often?
- Am I defining my predicate correctly? Are predicate not supposed to contain this much internal data?
- What would be a better solution than defining yet another internal object attribute?

Here's the relevant portion of my code. I did not describe the `Object` class in much detail because its attributes do not contribute to the problem.

```
class Predicate
{
public:
  Predicate()
  {
    // fill _attributes map with attribute values for all objects
  }

  bool operator()(const Object& a, const Object& b) const
  {
    std::map<Object, double>::const_iterator firstPos = _attributes.find( a );
    std::map<Object, double>::const_iterator secondPos = _attributes.find( b );

    // throw error if one of the objects could not be found

    return( firstPos->second < secondPos->second );
  }

private:
  std::map<Object, double> _attributes;
};

// Later, in order to sort the container
_container.sort( Predicate() );
```

Comment: how does `_attributes` get initialized at all? EDIT: sorry, just noticed the comment in the ctor

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One solution would be to construct your attributes map once, outside of the predicate, and have the predicate hold a `const` reference to the map. Another option would be to pass an `std::ref` or `boost::ref` to the predicate to your sorting function. This will avoid unnecessary copies of the `Predicate`'s `std::map` data member.

```
Predicate p; // builds map internally
_container.sort( boost::ref(p) );
```

Comment: Would this work even though `boost::multi_index_container::sort()` does not expect a (const) reference to a predicate?

Comment: @Gnosophilon a `boost::ref` is an object that get copied around, but otherwise behaves like a reference.

Answer (score 3):

The comparison object gets copied --this situation mimics the one with C++ standard algorithms, and there are reasons why the comparison object is not taken by reference that we need not get into.

The solution is to use `boost::ref` in combination with `boost::bind`:

```
#include <boost/bind.hpp>
#include <boost/ref.hpp>

...

Predicate p;
_container.sort(boost::bind<bool>(boost::ref(p),_1,_2));
```

Comment: Actually, I would be interested in the reason. Are sorting predicates supposed to be as "small" as possible, so to speak, such that many copies of them do not hinder performance?

Answer (score 1):

@Gnosophilon, the reason is: function objects are defined by C++ in such a way that having a non-const `operator()` is permissible. This would make the following illegal:

```
template<typename F>void call(const F& f){f();}

struct foo{void operator()(){}};

int main()
{
  call(foo());
}
```

since `foo()` is captured as a const reference and `foo::operator()` is not const. To make things worse, a temporary such as `foo()` is always captured as const, so adding this overload

```
template<typename F>void call(F& f){f();}
```

won't work either. The only solution then is capturing by value, which assumes that the function object is inexpensive to copy.

In C++11 this could have been solved with rvalue references, but the thing has nevertheless stayed the same.

Comment: Thanks, this is very insightful. I wish I could accept more than one answer.

Comment: I flagged a few of your 2nd answers to the same question: these should ideally be merged into an expanded answer. +1 on your other answer, of course.